# Unittesting Django CreateView with mock library

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, mocking

I'm trying to test my CreateView by posting some data and mocking models' `save()` method.

```
class BaseViewTest(TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.user = UserFactory()
       self.factory = RequestFactory()

class MuayeneCreateViewTest(BaseViewTest):

   def test_get(self):
        request = self.factory.get(reverse('muayene:create'))
        request.user = self.user
 
        response = MuayeneCreateView.as_view()(request)
 
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue('form' in response.context_data)
        self.assertTrue('muayene/muayene_form.html' in response.template_name)

    @patch('muayene.models.Muayene.save', MagicMock(name="save"))
    def test_post(self):
        hasta = HastaFactory()
        ilac1 = IlacFactory()
        ilac2 = IlacFactory()
        data = {
            'hasta': hasta.id,
            'tarih': str(datetime.date.today()),
            'yakinma': 'Kusma',
            'kullandigi_ilaclar': [ilac1.id, ilac2.id],
            'öntani_tani': 'Öntanı ve tanı',
            'öneri_görüsler': 'Öneri ve Görüşler',
            'özel_notlar': 'Özel notlar'
        }
 
        request = self.factory.post(reverse('muayene:create'), data)
        request.user = self.user
 
        response = MuayeneCreateView.as_view()(request)
 
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
 
        self.assertTrue(Muayene.save.called)
        self.assertEqual(Muayene.save.call_count, 1)
```

Here is `MuayeneCreateView`:

```
class MuayeneCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = Muayene
    form_class = MuayeneCreateForm
```

and traceback:

```
ERROR: test_post (tests.test_muayene.MuayeneCreateViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1157, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/egegunes/Dropbox/Programs/hastatakip/tests/test_muayene.py", line 153, in test_post
    response = MuayeneCreateView.as_view()(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 256, in post
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 222, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 201, in form_valid
    self.object = form.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 452, in save
    self._save_m2m()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 434, in _save_m2m
    f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1618, in save_form_data
    setattr(instance, self.attname, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 480, in __set__
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 468, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 751, in __init__
    (instance, self.source_field_name))
ValueError: "<Muayene: ID: None - 2016-07-31 - Bob Baz>" needs to have a value for field "muayene" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I couldn't figure out what causes this error. `Muayene` instance is used by some other models but IMO this error must not show up unless I try to create one of those models with this instance.

#### Edit

`Muayene` model:

```
class Muayene(models.Model):
    hasta = models.ForeignKey(
        'hasta.Hasta', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    tarih = models.DateField(
        default = timezone.now
    )
    yakinma = models.TextField(
        max_length = 255,
        blank = True, 
        null = True
    )
    kullandigi_ilaclar = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ilac,
        blank = True
    )
    baki = models.TextField(
        max_length = 255,
        blank = True, 
        null = True
    )
    öntani_tani = models.TextField(
        max_length = 255,
        blank = True, 
        null = True
    )
    öneri_görüsler = models.TextField(
        max_length = 255,
        blank = True, 
        null = True
    )
    özel_notlar = models.TextField(
        max_length = 255,
        blank = True, 
        null = True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        tarih = str(self.tarih)
        hasta = str(self.hasta.ad + " " +  self.hasta.soyad)
        pk = str(self.pk)
        return "ID: " + pk + " - " + tarih + " - " + hasta
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('muayene:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    def was_today(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        if  today - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.tarih <= today:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Models in relation with `Muayene`:

```
class Recete(models.Model):
    hasta = models.ForeignKey(
        'hasta.Hasta', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    muayene = models.ForeignKey(
        'muayene.Muayene',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    tarih = models.DateField(
        default = timezone.now        
    )
    ilaclar = models.ManyToManyField(Ilac)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tarih)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('muayene:recete-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Rapor(models.Model):
    hasta = models.ForeignKey(
        'hasta.Hasta', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    muayene = models.ForeignKey(
        'muayene.Muayene',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    tarih = models.DateField(
        default = timezone.now        
    )
    tani = models.CharField(
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        max_length = 255        
    )
    gun = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default = 1        
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hasta)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('muayene:rapor-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class LaboratuvarIstek(models.Model):
    hasta = models.ForeignKey(
        'hasta.Hasta', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    muayene = models.ForeignKey(
        'muayene.Muayene',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    tarih = models.DateField(
        default = timezone.now        
    )
    istekler = models.ManyToManyField(Laboratuvar)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hasta)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('muayene:lab-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Please show the `Muayene` model and its `muayene` relationship's model.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually see failing reason in your traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 452, in save
    self._save_m2m()
```

That is because your view doesn't call model's save method directly. Instead it gets form that is used for model (or creates one with factory) and calls form's save method. You can check this method at `django.forms.models.BaseModelForm.save`. So if you really want to count calls on model instance and don't wanna fail test, you shoud mock `django.forms.models.BaseModelForm._save_m2m` too, because it gets called in form's save method.